# Poisson Distribution to Calculate plane crashes

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The number of passenger planes that crash every day follows the Poisson distribution with parameter p. The number of crashes each day is independent.
What is the probability of exactly 3 planes crashing in 8 days?

I think this exercise is somewhat unclear since it doesn't give enough information. Is there a solution to it, because I can't think of anything. 
So, far I've used the Poisson distribution mass probability and I didn't reached any conclusions.

Comment: You should get a result wich depends on $p$.

Comment: @AlexR Can you be a little more specific? I've tried using the mass probability ,but I can't reach a definitive number

Comment: Can you do it if p = 0.3? If you can, replace the 0.3 with the symbol p. This is what @AlexR means.

Comment: @Paul Thanks Paul. However, I don't think I am allowed to replace p with an independent number.

Comment: If $X$ is the number of crashes in $1$ day and has distribution $Poisson(p)$ and if $Y$ is the number of crashes in $8$ days then $Y$ has distribution $Poisson(8p)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps use of the letter $p$ for the Poisson average daily rate is confusing you. This is *not* a probability. Many books use $\lambda$ (lower-case Greek 'lambda') for this rate.

You may not be able to replace $p$ with a number in your final answer, but
that may be a worthwhile suggestion to get started understanding
the problem. Suppose the average rate per day is 0.3 as in one
of the comments. Then the average rate per 8 days is 8(0.3) = 2.4.
(Notice that the rate 2.4 > 1 cannot possibly be a probability.)

Then let $X_8 \sim Pois(2.4)$ and use the Poisson formula to
find $P(X_8 = 3) = e^{-2.4}(2.4)^3/3!.$ I'm guessing that
formula may be in your textbook or notes.

Now that you see how it works for an average daily crash rate of 0.3,
you should be able to write $P(X_8 = 3)$ in terms of the general
symbol $p$ (or $\lambda$ or whatever).

In any Poisson problem you have to make sure that you use the
average rate that applies to the question at hand. That may or
may not be the rate given at the start of the problem. For example,
here we had to adjust the given rate of p per day to the rate 8p per eight days in order to answer a question about what happens over eight days.